# Бот не оправляет сообщения aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть бот, который ловит фото и видео и пересылает их в тг канал. Пока отправлять только фото/видео отдельно всё нормально, но если отправить фото и видео одним сообщением, выдает ошибку:

```
 File "C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\python\рр\bot.py", line 71, in get_foto
    del data["time"]
  File "C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\a
iogram\dispatcher\storage.py", line 449, in __delitem__
    del self._data[key]
KeyError: 'time'
```

Сам код:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo", 'video'])
async def get_foto(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.photo:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            if type(data.get('photo')) is list:
                data['photo'].append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
                data["time"] = time()
                return
            else:
                data['photo'] = [message.photo[-1].file_id]
                data["time"] = time()
        wait_time = 3
        while time() - data["time"] < wait_time:
            await sleep(0.5)
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            poli = types.MediaGroup()
            for i in data['photo']:
                poli.attach_photo(photo=i)
            del data["time"]
            del data["photo"]
    elif message.video:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            if type(data.get('video')) is list:
                data['video'].append(message.video.file_id)
                data["time"] = time()
                return
            else:
                data['video'] = [message.video.file_id]
                data["time"] = time()
        wait_time = 3
        while time() - data["time"] < wait_time:
            await sleep(0.5)
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            poli = types.MediaGroup()
            for i in data['video']:
                poli.attach_video(video=i)
            del data["time"]
            del data["video"]
    await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=config.chat_id, media=poli)
```

Comment: А зачем вы `del` делаете?

Comment: а разве  не надо?

Comment: Надо, но вы если уж и модифицировали мой вариант, то хотя бы подумали для чего я это делал. Сделайте перед удалением проверку типа `if data.get('time'): ...` Хотя этого не хватит

Comment: добавил. но фото и видео отправляются в разных сообщениях

Comment: В апи бота в принципе нет возможности отправить фото и видео в одном сообщении. Только как файлы для скачивания